# Python magic mock elastic search client calls not working when using from import

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I am trying to mock calls to elastic search using magic mock. It is working fine if I use `import elasticsearch` but not working if I use `from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch`

Below test prints me hello string.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock, TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import elasticsearch



class TestJobApis(TestCase):

    @mock.patch("elasticsearch.Elasticsearch",MagicMock(return_value="heellloo"))
    def test_get_all_jobs(self):
        print(elasticsearch.Elasticsearch())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But this one not working. It goes to actual elastic search call.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock, TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch


class TestJobApis(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("elasticsearch.Elasticsearch",MagicMock(return_value="heellloo"))
    def test_get_all_jobs(self):
        print(Elasticsearch())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

How can I achieve the same result in case of from import as well. Because I have used this approach in our code to test. Can I achieve this by changing patch parameter ?

Comment: `patch` required target as `'package.module.ClassName'`, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch

Comment: Thanks for the hint @sagarr.  I have to do `@mock.patch("test.test_job_api.Elasticsearch",
                MagicMock(return_value="heellloo"))`
Kindly add it as an answer.

Comment: Honestly, you figured it out yourself, so please [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock, TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

class TestJobApis(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("test.test_job_api.Elasticsearch",MagicMock(return_value="heellloo"))
    def test_get_all_jobs(self):
        print(Elasticsearch())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The above fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding in some details to make it slightly more clear since I did not quite understand the above solution.

Say your directory is as follows.

```
project/
  source_python.py
  test_source.py
```

In test_source.py:

```
class YourTestClass(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("project.test_source.Elasticsearch", MagicMock(return_value="heellloo"))
    def test_get_all_jobs(self):
        assert Elasticsearch() == "heellloo"
```